# Storage for large volume of objects

Tags: c#

I'm building a C# application where the end users won't have any sql database manager. I need a way of storing around 3 million objects (with roughly 10-20 string fields) so that the program can import the info. I've tried binary formatting but im getting out of memory exceptions due to the large amount of data. Is there any other way to store the objects in a speedy and size efficient way?

Thank You

Comment: This is exactly what databases are designed for.  Try an embedded sql data source.

Comment: 3m objects is huge for a flat file. There are plenty of lightweight databases you can use and deploy such as SQLite and SQL CE which would do all the hardwork for you and be more efficient. Otherwise you'll have to look into streaming your data rather than reading the entire thing in at once or use [MemoryMappedFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx)

Comment: why waste your time reinventing the wheel..There are many free database's available..why not use them..

Comment: When you say "storing", is this long term or just temporary for the duration of a process of sorts? When you say "users won't have any sql database manager" are you saying they don't want to maintain a database? Or that a DBA is not available to manage a database?

Comment: "*speedy and size efficient*" Let's not get greedy here, Mr. [Space-Time Tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff).

Comment: Either split the job up into separate processes (a bit like forking in Unix) or only read the data as you need it, using files for paging.

Answer (score 5):

This is what databases are made for. It doesn't matter that the end user won't have a database system already. There are a number of light-weight options available that you can deploy with your app. Here are three:

- If you are Windows-only, then the Access database engine is built into the operating system. Just build a database with only table definitions (no records), and your app will be able to use it.
- There is an implementation of sqlite completely in managed code, allowing you to compile it directly into your app.
- Sql Server Compact Edition is just two *.dll files that are easy to deploy with the app.

None of these options require you to have anything running in the background on the target system.

Comment: Based on personal experience, I would stay away from the Access database engine. It has lots of quirks you'll have to learn that are less intuitive than other lightweight database engines.

Comment: I agree, but I also need to mention that this is a little less true than it used to be. The post-Office 2007 Access uses a completely new engine that is a lot cleaner.

Comment: Thank you all so much a embedded sql engine would be perfect could you link me to some documentation? also would this work with a mac using mono to run the app?

Comment: I read up about the access file use and it was a little too scary to try for a time constrained project

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/). This is [designed](http://www.hdfgroup.org/about/hdf_technologies.html) for large-volume, high IO, distributed and high-performance computations. It is very flexible and imposes no install restriction on your application (can be completely self contained).

Hope this helps!